# 'NoneType' object is not iterable - data import

Tags: python, pandas

need some help here to eliminate this error. Here is the code - the # was the original code which running wonderful and I tried to adapt:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
from genhurst import genhurst
from datetime import datetime
import pandas_datareader as pdr 


df = pdr.DataReader('BTC-USD', 'yahoo', datetime(2014,1,1), datetime(2019,10,25))

# df=pd.read_csv('inputData_USDCAD.csv')

y=df.loc[df['Adj Close']]

# y=df.loc[df['Time']==1659, 'Close']


results=adfuller(y, maxlag=1, regression='c', autolag=None)
print(results)

# Find Hurst exponent
H, pVal=genhurst(np.log(y))
print("H=%f pValue=%f" % (H, pVal))
```

Those are the error messages:

> File "", line 14, in 
>       y=df.loc[df['Adj Close']]
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\apros\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py",
>   line 1424, in **getitem**
>       return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\apros\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py",
>   line 1839, in _getitem_axis
>       return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\apros\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py",
>   line 1133, in _getitem_iterable
>       keyarr, indexer = self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis, raise_missing=False)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\apros\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py",
>   line 1089, in _get_listlike_indexer
>       keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\apros\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 3443, in _reindex_non_unique
>       indexer, missing = self.get_indexer_non_unique(target)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\apros\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 4801, in get_indexer_non_unique
>       indexer, missing = self._engine.get_indexer_non_unique(tgt_values)
>
> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 295, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_indexer_non_unique
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: whats the content of `df['Adj Close']` what do you see if you do `print(type(df['Adj Close']), "\n", df['Adj Close'])`

Comment: what's in the column 'Adj Close'? if it's not boolean, doing `df.loc[df['Adj Close']]` is probably wrong - i guess you probably want `df.loc[df['Adj Close'] == 'some condition']`?

Comment: I had a look at the data set and `df['Adj Close']` is a series of floats. So I am not sure what you are expecting to do with the `loc()` method here when you are not filtering on any condition. Maybe edit your question to explain what your trying to achieve

Comment: for example if you wanted to select into y all rows which the Adj Close value is less than 200 then you can do `y=df.loc[df['Adj Close'] < 200]` this will return you a df of `[2 rows x 6 columns]`

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that you have read your *df* from *pdr.DataReader*.

But this is too little information to say anything about the source of your error.
Actually, the way how you read the *df* is of **very little** importance here.

Rather show a piece of your *df*.

An important detail is also **what are data types of each column**, especially that
used as the criterion field (*Adj Close*).

I suppose that it has been read as **string** (or some outher type),
but you expect a **boolean** type there.

Mabe you should compare the value in *Adj Close* column with some concrete value?

Check also whether your *df* actually contains a column with this name.

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys!!

the .loc method was the problem, it seems to work by applying y = df['Adj Close'] only`

```
@author: Ernest
"""

# Example 2: Using ADF Test for Mean Reversion
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas_datareader as pdr 
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
from datetime import datetime



def genhurst(z):
# =============================================================================
# calculation of Hurst exponent given log price series z
# =============================================================================
    z=pd.DataFrame(z)

    taus=np.arange(np.round(len(z)/10)).astype(int) # We cannot use tau that is of same magnitude of time series length 
    logVar=np.empty(len(taus)) # log variance

    for tau in taus:
        logVar[tau]=np.log(z.diff(tau).var(ddof=0))

    X=np.log(taus)    
    Y=logVar[:len(taus)]
    X=X[np.isfinite(logVar)]
    Y=Y[np.isfinite(logVar)]
#    pd.DataFrame(np.asmatrix([X, Y]).T).to_csv('XY.csv')

    X = sm.add_constant(X)
#    plt.scatter(X[:,1], Y) # for debug only
    model=sm.OLS(Y, X)
    results=model.fit()
    H=results.params[1]/2
    pVal=results.pvalues[1]
    return H, pVal


df = pdr.DataReader('BCH-USD', 'yahoo', datetime(2017,1,1), datetime(2019,10,25))

# df=pd.read_csv('inputData_USDCAD.csv')

y = df['Adj Close']

# y=df.loc[df['Time']==1659, 'Close']


results=adfuller(y, maxlag=1, regression='c', autolag=None)
print(results)

# Find Hurst exponent
H, pVal=genhurst(np.log(y))
print("H=%f pValue=%f" % (H, pVal))
```

BR Andreas